# Is my volume group dead?

Tags: lvm, scientific-linux

I have a notebook with Scientific Linux 6.4, also a Desktop PC with SL 6.4. The PC didn't booted in a day, saying KERNEL PANIC :) So I tried to get the disk from the PC to the notebook (VolGroup is the notebooks VG, VGSTUFF is the PC's):

```
[root@localhost ~] vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               VGSTUFF
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  14
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                6
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               465,26 GiB
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              119106
  Alloc PE / Size       108417 / 423,50 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       10689 / 41,75 GiB
  VG UUID               XXXX

  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               VolGroup
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               3
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               465,26 GiB
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              119106
  Alloc PE / Size       119106 / 465,26 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               XXXX

[root@localhost ~] find /dev | grep -i VGSTUFF
[root@localhost ~]
```

**QUESTION**: But even after I do a pvscan/vgscan... the /dev entry doesn't gets created. WHY? I can see the volumegrpu in the vgdsiplay.. I just want to run an FSCK on the LV's on the VG from the PC, because maybe that would fix the kernel panic on the PC. (ps.: there were times when we just unplugged the PC from the power, maybe that caused the corruption..)

Comment: try `vgchange -ay` to activate the logical volumes

Comment: yepp, that was the solution :) can you post this as answer?

Comment: Added as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running `pvscan` and `vgscan` to find the volume groups, you need to activate the logical volumes. You do that by running:

```
vgchange -ay
```